# Adode Air Windows Installer: How to set "Start in" parameter in desktop shortcut during add installation

Tags: air, windows-installer, desktop-application, shortcut

I created Adobe Native Installer for Windows. During installation it creates desktop shortcut, but with empty **Start in** parameter.

[image: Empty Start in parametr]

For this reason, *current dir* in running air application is depended on start type: if i started app directly from ProgramFiles dir - it has correct *current dir* (C:\ProgramFiles\MyAppName), but if I started from Desktop shortcut it has *C:\Users\Username\Desktop* as current dir.

If i fill **Start in** field in shortcut options - it has correct current dir during running. Most of all native windows apps have this field filled.

My question is:
**Is it possible to setup Adobe Installer to fill this field during installation?**

(How to find Adobe Air `invocation.currentDirectory` or `File.applicationDirectory` i know, but it is not what i ask)

Comment: How did you create the installer?

Comment: In FlashBulder:
Project->Export Release Build -> (Checked) Native Installer. 

Or using mxmlc and adl compilers. I use both of them in different situations